# What is the name of the IDE feature that pins a line containing an open curly brace to the top of the screen after you scroll past it?

Tags: ide, jetbrains-ide

In some IDEs, if you're editing a function, class, if block etc. that is too large to fit on one screen, and you scroll past a line containing an opening curly brace, it will be pinned to the top of the screen until you scroll past the corresponding closing one.  JetBrains IDEs notably have this feature.  For example, in this file, if the window was scrolled such that the region betweeen `[[[ ]]]` was visible:

```java
class FooClass {
    public static void foo() {
        // do foo stuff
    }
    public static void bar() {
        System.out.println("foo");
        if(bazPredicate()) {
            System.out.println("bar");
[[[
            System.out.println("baz");
         } else {
            System.out.println("not ready yet");
         }
    }
    public static boolean bazPredicate() {
]]]
         return getFrobnicator().readyState() == 2;
    }
    private static Frobnicator getFrobnicator() {
         ...
    }
}
```

an IDE with the feature I'm describing would display this:

```java
class FooClass {
    public static void bar() {
        if(bazPredicate()) {
----------------------------------------------------
            System.out.println("baz");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not ready yet");
        }
    }
    public static boolean bazPredicate() {
```

What is the official name of this feature?